# How can i prevent git from updating the rcs $Id: tags in my repo?

Tags: git, gitattributes

I have a repo that contains some imported sources that contain `$Id: <hex>` rcs codes in comments. When i clone that repo `git` is changing all those hex numbers in all those sources. Even doing a `git reset --hard` doesn't remove the changes. How do I prevent git from doing this?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_ident

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a `.gitattributes` file in the imported sources that was explicitly enabling the `ident` feature. Commenting this out fixed the issue.